# How to deal with one single cell containg multiple values?

Tags: sql, database-design, database-normalization

I'm having an exercise requiring to create two table for a travel business:

[Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmY6l.png)

[Booking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmVTE.png)

it turns out that the column activities in the Booking table references from the Activities table. However it contains multiple value. How do I sort it out? If I insert multiple rows there will possibly duplication in the Booking's primary key.

Comment: Use a separate table, often called a junction table (you can look it up on Wikipedia).

Comment: so how about multiple values in a cell in a column which does not reference from the other tables? I have both case in my exercise.

Comment: it is not good to have an array of elements in a cell. If you are using relational databases (which of course you are) then you should do as @Gordon Linoff said

Comment: If you have to extract the values from the cell, try treating it as a string, separating by ", ", storing in an array and iterating through the array inserting the values in that junction table Gordon Linoff told you about

Comment: You actually need four tables. Activities appear to relate to Adventure codes, not booking.  So you need [Booking], [Adventure], [Activities] and [AdventureActivities].

Comment: @Crowcoder the ActivitiesCode and AdventureCode are different, I created Adven table though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gordon mentioned you should refactor your tables for better normalization. If I interpret your intent correctly this is more like what your schema should look like. Booking should only contain an ID for adventure and an ID for Customer. You will add a row to [AdventureActivity] for each activity booked on a [Booking]. With this design you can `JOIN` tables and get all the data you require without having to try to parse out multiple values in a column.
[image]